# ffmpeg still fails if captured late in the video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video clip that is `12.035177s` long.  When I attempt to take a still of one frame it fails:

command:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -ss 00:00:08.1 -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -y -frames:v 1 ./test9-before.jpg
```

error:

> Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

However, if I take the still from slightly earlier in the clip it works (note 8.0 in the working example vs 8.1 in the failing example):

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -ss 00:00:08.0 -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -y -frames:v 1 ./test9-before.jpg
```

Additionally, if I move the `-ss` to after `-i` (the output buffer) with the failing command above, it also works.

Comparing a diff of the debug output of the working vs non-working I see these lines in the failing example:

> [h264 @ 0x7fbc3a01c200] Frame num gap 15 13

these lines (or something similar) is present much more often:

> cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)

> 168    [h264 @ 0x7fbc3a01c200] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2

this is also present in the failing example:

> [out_0_0 @ 0x7fbc3c6053c0] EOF on sink link out_0_0:default.

In the succeeding example, I see this line which is not present in the failing example:

> 7 Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
> n
> 138 [image2 @ 0x7fba2f812000] Opening './test9-before.jpg' for writing
> 139 [file @ 0x7fba30130000] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
> 140 [AVIOContext @ 0x7fba2e611b00] Statistics: 0 seeks, 2 writeouts

[image]

Comment: Share full debug log.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4yThfSQp @Gyan

Comment: for comparison, the debug output from moving the `-ss` flag to after `-i`: `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -ss 00:00:08.1 -y -frames:v 1 ./test9-before.jpg` - https://pastebin.com/DYDHxfr8

Comment: To me it looks like when you do not have a keyframe after the point at which you are attempting to take the still, the `-ss` doesn't seek correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try to capture 2 (or 3 etc. frames) around the point of interest?

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -ss 00:00:08.1 -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -y -frames:v 2 ./test9-before%d.jpg
```

Say 1 frame back (in time scale) and 1 frame ahead, if it's 15 fps maybe ~:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -ss 00:00:08.033 -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -y -frames:v 3 ./test9-before%d.jpg
```

Comment: `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -ss 00:00:08.1 -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -y -frames:v 2 ./test1.jpg` fails with "Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)" - same thing with 3 frames

Comment: Then I'd try dumping all frames and try to take the picture by its number/time per frame.
It's MJPEG, so every frame should be separate, but one thing I noticed now in the logs is that the bitrate seems very low, 1536x2048x15 fps and just 200kbps if I saw correctly. Maybe there's not enough bandwidth to encode a frame?

Also, given the 15 fps, 8.1 s is between frames, while 8.0 is exactly at frame moment. Frame period is 1/15 = 0.0666666 s

Have you tried at  8.1333 s or 8.0666 which is also at a frame time? (8.033 was for 30 fps)

BTW, if the video is not private, could you share it?

Comment: Interesting, `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -ss 00:00:08.0666 -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -y -frames:v 1 ./test1.jpg` does return a still.  Unfortunately this video belongs to a customer so I cannot share it. I'll look around for one we could share.

Comment: However this fails: `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -ss 00:00:09 -accurate_seek -i ./25e13b0b-d2e6-426a-920b-6bb2445a1324-original.ps -y -frames:v 1 ./test1.jpg` - presumably if there is a frame at exactly 8s, then there is one at exactly 9s, correct? `00:00:09.1998`, `09.1332`, `09.0333` and `09.0666` also fail FWIW

Comment: Yes, if it's about the logic for precise time. So I'd generate a script for each frame time (by 0.0666666) and see which renders a frame. NP about the video, if it's about ffmpeg, I guess it would be replicated by any 15 fps video with similar features.BTW, something else:  ffmpeg was known to have issues with frame-precise seeking.

Comment: "Slice not frame accurate #2927 " https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/2927#issuecomment-520046226 
"ferdnyc commented on 9 Aug 2019" OpenShot's current slicing code includes a bit of wiggle room that @jonoomph introduced because ffmpeg itself can't always be relied on for strict frame accuracy

Comment: A work-around would be to use OpenCV, seek by it and use cv2.imwrite(...) (or in C++ or whatever is convenient, Python is the easiest I think). I've developed such an editor/seeker for rough cropping and encoding segments for another frame-precise editor (not ffmpeg-based) and also to seek/quickly review and save frames.

Comment: "00:00:09.1998, 09.1332, 09.0333 and 09.0666"  - maybe the exact rounding matters... Then I'd generate commands with a smaller step, even 0.01 or 0.001 s...